# C Structures - Change values

Tags: c, struct

I'm trying to change certain values of a struct pointer.

```
struct gtaVars_s {
    int godmode;
};

struct gtaVars_s *gtaVars;

void test() {
     gtaVars->godmode = 1;
}
```

Why does `test()` fail?

I've tried changing the `->` to `.` but that only gave me errors.

Also I've read various articles about structs but none of them seem to give me an answer about this specific problem.

Comment: You never allocate memory for `gtaVars` or initialize the pointer in any other meaningful way?

Comment: In the snippet posted, `gtaVars` has a value of `0` and so you will try to dereference a `NULL` pointer.

Comment: @WeatherVane: How do you know it is 0?

Comment: You might need, for example `gtaVars = malloc(sizeof *gtaVars);` before `gtaVars->godmode = 1;`

Comment: @ScottHunter is a static variable, which is automatically initialised to `0`, but my comment presumes that `0` is synonymous with `NULL`.

Comment: @WeatherVane: I guess I missed the `static` keyword, as well as the part of the spec that says uninitialized variables default to 0.

Comment: @ScottHunter what you missed is that `struct gtaVars_s *gtaVars;` is not inside any function and therefore is pre-initialised to `0`, in the absence of explicit initialisation.

Comment: You should try to find a tutorial about memory allocation

Comment: Hasn´t GTA:V enough available mod-menus? :-)

Comment: Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does test() fail?

`test()` seems not to be called from `main()` or one of the called functions from `main()`, which is required by the C syntax.

> I've tried changing the `->` to `.` but that only gave me errors.

That is because you *attempt* to access a structure object by a pointer. If you use a pointer to access contents of an object of a structure, only `->` is allowed.

Why I said "*attempt*"?

Because you never allocated memory for the structure pointed to by `gtaVars` in the provided example, so it shall fail in either case.

---

What you need to do is for example to allocate memory via `malloc()` and also call `test()` from `main()`.

Don´t forget to `free()` dynamically allocated memory to deallocate the memory previously allocated by `malloc()`.

I also passed the pointer as parameter instead of to use a global pointer regarding readability and maintenance:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct gtaVars_s {
    int godmode;
};

void test(struct gtaVars_s *);

int main(void)
{
   struct gtaVars_s *gtaVars = malloc(sizeof(*gtaVars));
   test(gtaVars);

   printf("godmode is %d.",gtaVars->godmode);

   free(gtaVars);
}

void test(struct gtaVars_s *gtaVars) {
     gtaVars->godmode = 1;
}
```

Output:

```
godmode is 1.
```

---

Personal side notation:

Hasn´t GTA:V already enough available mod-menus with god mode? :-)

Comment: I appreciate the example, that explains and helps a lot in my journey to learn C. About your personal side notation, I see you're a man of culture for knowing what this is about.